# Find location of specific character in NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can I find the location of a specific character in an NSString?

I have tried this but it returns an empty range (I want to find the location of the '?'):

```
NSRange range = [@"This is a ? test to see if it works" rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"?"]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must doing something else wrong. Because this is absolutely correct and returns `{10, 1}`. At least on my mac it does ;-)

Comment: Debugger shows 0,0 but the if statement checking this fails... 
hmmmm...
Thanks anyway for confirming.

Comment: @V1ru8 Also the app crashes, when I try to NSLog(@"Range %@", range);

Comment: you're trying to log a struct as an NSObject, that's not possible and will lead into your experienced crash. Use something like this: `NSLog(@"Range: %@", NSStringFromRange(range));`

Answer (score 3):

maybe this will work?

```
NSString* s = @"hello?";
NSRange range = [s rangeOfString:@"?"];
```